# Реализация наследования не через class, а через prototype

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype

Есть задачка:

Создайте класс `FormatError`, который наследует от встроенного класса `SyntaxError`. Класс должен поддерживать свойства `message`, `name` и `stack`.

**Решение через class:**

```js
class FormatError extends SyntaxError {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.name = "FormatError";
  }
}
```

А как решить через функцию конструктор?

**Пробую так:**

```js
function FormatError (message) {
  this.name = `FormatError`
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(FormatError.prototype, SyntaxError.prototype);
```

Наследовать получается, но как выполнить `super` из классов в функции конструкторе — не понимаю. Или нужно вручную переносить свойства из `SyntaxError`?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, `super` можно вызвать только при использовании классов. Могу ошибаться.